# Azure Ubuntu VM port forwarding

Tags: ubuntu, azure, azure-virtual-desktop

I am new to this forum and new to server management. I am working on an iot project and want to use Azure VM. I have port on azure vm which is 8080 and want to forward it to 80 port. Without load balancer, how can I do it? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, you need something in front of the VM to do the port forwarding. A load balancer is usually the simplest option.